# Calling a REST webservice from a cron job

Tags: java, web-services, cron

I have a database table that contains threshold data.
I want a job to run every 5 minutes to poll the DB and get this threshold data.

I am using REST webservice and I wanted to integrate the REST webservice with a cron Job.

Can some one tell me what are the files I would need to write to complete the cron job and webservice integration.

Comment: have you looked at this, http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ and have a scheduler in your ws to poll data?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) as @Kin Cheung suggested that website has sufficient information.

But how I would achieve what you want to is:

Write a Shell Script to hit the Rest End Point and store the result and do whatever you want to do with the response and schedule the script with Linux CRON JOBS

```
output=`curl --header "HEADER-KEY: VALUE" www.google.com` -->Replace google with your rest end point
echo $output;
```

How to run a CRON every 5 minute:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/neeraj/myScript.sh
```